# Angular material datepicker to work only with date and completely ignore time and time timezone

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, angular-material-datetimepicker

I have wrapped Angular Material datepicker component into my own component

```
<mat-form-field ...>
<mat-label>...</mat-label>

<input matInput [min]="min" [max]="max" [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="value"
       #inputName="ngModel">

<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>

<mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

and i need it to only work with date and completely ignore time and time timezone (use case is entering date of birth).

So i want it to show date as it is received from backend and change nothing (ignore web browser timezone, system timezone anything). Solution needs to be configurable only on component, not globally on project.

I tried solution from net, with moment adapter, with customer adapter implementing parse and format methods, but nothing is working. Every time i change timezone locally, it changes date -+ 1 day depending on time+timezone received from backend.

So im looking for some ideas. It's clear that i'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Is there any fix for above issue ?